# Displaying a list with another aspect

Tags: haskell

I would like to know if it's possible for a list like this:

```
FavoriteList [('d',False), ('e',True), ('c',False)]
```

To be simply displayed like this:

```
{'d', 'e'*, 'c'}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

assuming you are talking about

```
favoriteList :: [(Char, Bool)]
favoriteList = [('d',False), ('e',True), ('c',False)]
```

and you want a list `['d','e','c']` (I hope the `*` got there by accident)
then it's just

```
λ> map fst favoriteList
"dec"
```

(where a list of characters is displayed as as string).

---

assuming you want the `{...}` format then you have to work a bit more.
Using `Data.List.intersperse` to *weave* in the `", "`s and an additional `show` to get the `' '` you can do it with:

```
λ> import Data.List(intersperse)
λ> "{" ++ (concat . intersperse ", " $ map (show . fst) favoriteList) ++ "}"
"{'d', 'e', 'c'}"
```

in case you are interested in the steps:

```
λ> map fst favoriteList
"dec"
λ> map (show . fst) favoriteList
["'d'","'e'","'c'"]
λ> intersperse ", " $ map (show . fst) favoriteList
["'d'",", ","'e'",", ","'c'"]
λ> concat . intersperse ", " $ map (show . fst) favoriteList
"'d', 'e', 'c'"
```

the `"{" ++ (..) ++ "}"` should be obvious I hope

---

assuming the `*` is in there because the second part of the tuple was `true` then you can do it like this:

```
λ> let stared (c,star) = if star then show c ++ "*" else show c
λ> "{" ++ (concat . intersperse ", " $ map stared favoriteList) ++ "}"
"{'d', 'e'*, 'c'}"
```

---

further assuming the `FavoriteList` was not a typo but a data-constructor:

```
data FavoriteList = FavoriteList [(Char, Bool)]

myList :: FavoriteList
myList = FavoriteList [('d',False), ('e',True), ('c',False)]
```

it's

```
λ> let stared (c,star) = if star then show c ++ "*" else show c
λ> let (FavoriteList xs) = myList in "{" ++ (concat . intersperse ", " $ map (stared) xs) ++ "}"
"{'d', 'e'*, 'c'}"
```

where I just used pattern-matching to get out the list again

---

#### complete code

```
import Data.List(intercalate)

data FavoriteList = FavoriteList [(Char, Bool)]

myList :: FavoriteList
myList = FavoriteList [('d',False), ('e',True), ('c',False)]

printList :: FavoriteList -> String
printList (FavoriteList xs) = 
  "{" ++ (intercalate ", " $ map stared xs) ++ "}"
  where  stared (c,star) = if star then show c ++ "*" else show c
```

(**PS**: as Chi pointed out I should have used `intercalate = concat . intersperse` instead)
example

```
λ> printList myList
"{'d', 'e'*, 'c'}"
```

*I hope that was all ;) *

Comment: Minor variants: we can use `intercalate ", "` instead. Also `(stared)` does not need parentheses. If this were an obfuscation contest, I'd write `stared (c,star) = show c ++ ['*'|star]`, but I'd frown a little to read that in actual code (and much in code suggested to beginners ;-)).

Comment: @chi thanks for the points (both good ones) - indeed the the `(...)` is just me editing the repeated line in GHCi (I saw/edited in the first occurrence but forgot the second) - `intercalate` I just forgot about ...

Comment: Sorry if I was a bit ambigous, should have known better. Yes the* is in there because the second part of the tuple is true and the FavoriteList was not a typo but a data-constructor. Thank you very much!